# window server r2 2008 administration password forgot

Tags: windows

I have forgotten window server r2 2008 administration password. I am facing problem to login with my current password. The error message is invalid password. Please help how to I break my password.

Comment: [Is it so hard to Google for the tools that Microsoft make for these situations](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7369.using-the-locksmith-dart-7-0-to-change-the-local-administrator-password.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

petri has a cool tool to do this... here is the link to the tiny iso file.

http://www.petri.co.il/uri/?pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/cd080802.zip

main page: http://www.petri.co.il/forgot_administrator_password.htm

Download the iso file (around 2 MB), burn it to a CD, and boot from it... and follow the instructions, you can reset your pass !